# Building a HTTP link inside a Spring bean which is not a Controller

Tags: spring

For a bean which emails users confirmation links, I'd like to generate the URL dynamically, which means that I should know:

- the protocol;
- the server (virtual host) name;
- the server port
- the context path.

on which the application is running.

I will not be running a Controller at that time, so I'd like to retrieve this data somehow.

I've found `ServletContextAware` so I'm using that for the context path, but have no idea for the rest. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure if you can get the server name / port number while not processing a request. 
On the other hand, if you are processing a request you can use the [ServletRequest interface](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could make the bean definition request-scoped, so Spring will create a new one for every http request. You then have the option of declaring an @Autowired HttpServletRequest field, and Spring will supply it for you. You can then use that request object to build your URLs.

There are some gotcha with scoped beans (see [here](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection)), but nothing serious.